# Fetching Weekday Name from Javascript Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a code snippet which gives me the date on selecting from Calender of JSdatepicker Library.

I am looking for a way to get the name of weekday with selected date ex: monday, tuesday etc...

Below is the usage of `jsDatepicker`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"inputField1",
            dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d",
            cellColorScheme:"beige"             
        });

    };
</script>
```

I checked out the documentation given in [jsDatePicker](http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php) But didn't got anything.
Can somebody help?

I also tried using jQuery Datepicker, but it doesn't work at all, below is the jQuery datepicker code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>    
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

For both cases my inout field to select and display date is:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [JsDatePick](http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php), here's one way to do so:

```
// Save returning object to variable
var dateSelector = new JsDatePick({
    useMode:2,
    target:"inputField1",
    dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d",
    cellColorScheme:"beige"             
});

// Use setOnSelectedDelegate to capture clicks
dateSelector.setOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
    // Get selected day from plug-in
    var day = dateSelector.getSelectedDay();

    // Create a JS native Date
    var date = new Date(day.year, day.month, day.day);

    // Get the day of the week (0 is Sunday)
    var dayOfTheWeek = date.getDay();

    // For demonstration purposes, place a string into input field
    var inputField = document.getElementById("inputField1");
    var dayOfTheWeekStr = '';

    switch (dayOfTheWeek) {
        case 0:
            dayOfTheWeekStr = 'Sunday';
            break;
        case 1:
            dayOfTheWeekStr = 'Monday';
            break;
        case 2:
            dayOfTheWeekStr = 'Tuesday';
            break;
        default:
            dayOfTheWeekStr = 'Wed.-Sat.';
            break;
    }

    inputField.value = dayOfTheWeekStr;
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLxM3/).

Answer (score 1):

For jquery datepicker here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/girish2040/UzdMS/)

```
$(function() {
    var dt = $("#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            onSelect: function (dt) {
                var wa = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
                var nd = new Date(Date.parse(dt));
                $(this).val(wa[nd.getDay()]+', '+dt);
            }
    });

});
```